# The project need to deployed before Windows IOT

Tags: windows-iot

Actually i've got a problems, i reopen a old project (2month) and try to deploy it on Windows IOT on my raspberry pi, put i receive this error :

The project "ProjectName" need to deployed before it can be started.

I've check the Deploy configuration, and all are correct.

Today, i update IOT with the last version

Thank's for your help

> Update :
>
> The problems is the update of visual studio RC1.

Comment: Did you update Visual Studio? I am not sure about this issue yet but maybe the project needs updating too or something? Or the .NET libraries?

Comment: All are up to date (Vs / RPI / Project Library) :(

Comment: I've got this message : >Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named '192.168.1.73'.  Connection request was rejected by the remote debugger. Ensure that the remote debugger is running in 'Windows Authentication' mode.

Comment: The problem is the Update RC1 ...

Comment: Can you post an answer about this please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please update with the latest version of Windows 10 IoT Core and Visual Studio 2015 with latest update (Update 1 when this question was answered).

It might possible that you are trying to deploy an app that has been already deployed and is configured as startup application.

**How do I resolve this issue?**

1. First you must revert back your startup app to default startup app or any other app that is not the app you want to deploy.
2. Now, reboot your Windows IoT device to start the newly configured startup app (or you can manually kill the current running startup app and Windows IoT will start newely configured startup app).
3. After rebooting your Windows IoT device, deploy your app from Visual Studio.

If problem still persists, please refer the following hackster ProTip to better understand how you can deploy & register an app as startup app:
https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-setting-startup-app-887ed0